# Having more control on LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder in netty

Tags: java, networking, tcp, netty, pipeline

I'm adding a `new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(64 * 1024, 0, 4)` at the start of my pipeline and it works just fine but nothing ever happens when the received integer (the first 4 bytes of the packet that represents the length of the actual packet) is negative or more than `64*1024` which is the maximum possible length.

I want the `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` to somehow notify me when the size of the coming packet is bigger than `64 * 1024` or is less than `1`

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write your own version of `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`. That said we could also add a protected method that people could override to validate the "parsed" message length. This way the customisation would be minimal on the users end.

Comment: I was reading a lot of code examples from netty and also watching some videos in youtube AND aren't you literally the creator of netty? I can't believe I marked someone else's answer with the green thingy. I'm pretty sure you don't care about it but still pretty hilarious to me

Comment: haha not the creator but yes I am the project lead for a few years now ;)

Answer (score 0):

When `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` discovers negative length it throws `CorruptedFrameException` with respective message. Such exceptions should be propagated to pipeline via `ChannelEvent`. So you can intercept and filter exceptions in handlers.